# How To Setup MongoDB Memory Server In NestJS for E2E Testing?

Tags: mongodb, testing, mongoose, nestjs

### What I want

I'm looking to integrate mongodb-memory-server in my E2E testing within NestJS.  I noticed that I need a mongodb instance to work with supertest, but I would like to not depend on an external database and would rather have the mongodb server in-memory.

### Problem

I tried setting up mongodb-memory-server in my E2E test suite, but a couple of my tests it getting back a **500 Internal Server Error** when the expected status code is supposed to be 201.  Here is my code:

`drive.e2e-spec.ts`

```js
import { HttpStatus, INestApplication } from '@nestjs/common';
import { getModelToken } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { Types, Model } from 'mongoose';
import * as request from 'supertest';

import { AppModule } from '#app.module';
import { CreateDriveDto } from '#drive/dto/create-drive.dto';
import { Drive, DriveDoc } from '#drive/schema/drive.schema';
import {
  closeInMongodConnection,
  rootMongooseTestModule,
} from 'test/util/MongooseTestModule';
import { dataFromJoi } from 'test/util/generate-valid-sample-data';
import { configTestApp } from 'test/util/setup-test-app';

const route = `/api/test/v2/drive`;

// generate valid sample data from Joi schema
const validCreateData = dataFromJoi(CreateDriveDto);

let moduleFixture: TestingModule;
let app: INestApplication;
let mockDriveModel: Model<DriveDoc>;

beforeAll(async () => {
  moduleFixture = await Test.createTestingModule({
    imports: [AppModule, rootMongooseTestModule()],
  }).compile();

  app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
  mockDriveModel = moduleFixture.get<Model<DriveDoc>>(
    getModelToken(Drive.name),
  );
  configTestApp(app);
  await app.init();
});

afterEach(async () => {
  await closeInMongodConnection();
});

afterAll(async () => {
  await app.close();
});

describe(`Integration Test :: Route ${route}`, () => {
  describe(`POST`, () => {
    test('Return 400 if request is invalid', async () => {
      await request(app.getHttpServer())
        .post(route)
        .send({})
        .expect(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
        .then((res) => {
          expect(res.body).toHaveProperty('statusCode');
          expect(res.body).toHaveProperty('message');
        });
    });

    test('Return 201 and create new entry if request is valid', async () => {
      await request(app.getHttpServer())
        .post(route)
        .send(validCreateData)
        .expect(HttpStatus.CREATED);
    });
  });

  describe(`GET`, () => {
    test('Return 200 and an array', async () => {
      const doc = await mockDriveModel.create(validCreateData);
      await request(app.getHttpServer())
        .get(route)
        .expect(HttpStatus.OK)
        .then((res) => {
          expect(Array.isArray(res.body)).toBeTruthy();
        });
    });
  });
});
```

`MongooseTestModule.ts`

```js
import { MongooseModule, MongooseModuleOptions } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { MongoMemoryServer } from 'mongodb-memory-server';
import { disconnect } from 'mongoose';

let mongod: MongoMemoryServer;

export const rootMongooseTestModule = (options: MongooseModuleOptions = {}) =>
  MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
    useFactory: async () => {
      mongod = await MongoMemoryServer.create();
      const mongoUri = mongod.getUri();
      return {
        uri: mongoUri,
        ...options,
      };
    },
  });

export const closeInMongodConnection = async () => {
  await disconnect();
  if (mongod) await mongod.stop();
};
```

### Discussion

The implementation that should be focused on is the `rootMongoseTestModule`, which is where mongodb-memory-server would be instantiated.  Setup doesn't seem to work. Any thoughts or advice?  I am also open to other testing strategies as well.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: @erasmus, I wasn't able to figure it out.  I actually ended up using a better solution.  I'm using Drone to handle automate our CI pipeline and one neat thing you can do with Drone is add services.  I ended up adding MongoDB services in Drone so that my backend service can run E2E tests using those MongoDB instances without depending on any in-memory databases.  Once the CI finished, those MongoDB instances would just get deleted.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I found to using { MongoMemoryServer } from 'mongodb-memory-server' in NestJs e2e tests is by manually setting the uri in whichever module we have our MongoDB set up. E.g. in SharedModule we could do something like:

```js
//...
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { MongoMemoryServer } from 'mongodb-memory-server';
//...

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
// ...
    }),
    MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => {
        let uri: string = configService.get<string>('MONGODB_URI'); // Must be defined in .env files for other envs
        if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') { // This is the extra code, 
 exclusively for e2e testing
          const mongod = await MongoMemoryServer.create(); // <-- in memory mongoDb
          uri = mongod.getUri();
          return { uri }; // All that is needed for locally using mongodb-memory-server
        }
        return { // Default for any other envs
          uri,
          auth: {
            username: configService.get<string>('MONGODB_USER'),
            password: configService.get<string>('MONGODB_PASSWORD'),
          },
          dbName: configService.get<string>('MONGODB_DATABASE'),
        };
      },
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
    MongooseModule.forFeature([
      { name: SomeType.name, schema: SomeTypeSchema },
    ]),
  ],
  providers: [
    MongoExceptionFilter,
  ],
  exports: [
    MongooseModule,
    MongoExceptionFilter, // <-- if you have it
//...
  ],
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

And in the `package.json` add/update this script:

```
 "test:e2e": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json",
```

With `cross-env NODE_ENV=test` you specify that by running this script `process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test'` is true.

Then in the e2e test you don't care about anything else than your tests:

```js
  describe('AppController (e2e)', () => {
    let app: INestApplication;
  
    beforeAll(async () => {
      const moduleFixture = await Test.createTestingModule({
        imports: [AppModule],
      }).compile();
  
      app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
      await app.init();
    });
```

And remove `MongooseTestModule.ts` since it is not used.

Comment: How can you handle connection in test? for example closing connection

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is looking for a simpler and cleaner solution. Here is how I integrated mongo-memory-server in nest.js

Create a test-db.module.ts file in ./test/ directory.

```
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { MongoMemoryServer } from 'mongodb-memory-server';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';

let mongod: MongoMemoryServer;

export const TestDbModule = MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
  imports: [ConfigModule],
  useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => {
    mongod = await MongoMemoryServer.create();
    const mongoUri = mongod.getUri();
    return {
      uri: mongoUri,
    };
  },
  inject: [ConfigService],
});

export const closeInMongodConnection = async () => {
  if (mongod) await mongod.stop();
};
```

Update the jest config to be

```
{
   "moduleFileExtensions": ["js", "json", "ts"],
   "rootDir": ".",
   "testEnvironment": "node",
   "testRegex": ".e2e-spec.ts$",
   "transform": {
   "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
},
   "moduleNameMapper": {
     "^src/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/$1"
   }
}
```

Lastly import the TestDbModule and related Code in your spec file.

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { MongooseModule, getModelToken } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { TemplatesService } from './templates.service';
import { CreateTemplateDto } from './dto/create-template.dto';
import { Template, TemplateSchema, TemplateType } from './templates.schema';
import {
  BadRequestException,
  ForbiddenException,
  NotFoundException,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { HelperService } from 'src/common/services/helper.service';
import mongoose, { Model } from 'mongoose';
import {
  TestDbModule,
  closeInMongodConnection,
} from '../../test/test-db.module';
import { UpdateTemplateDto } from './dto/update-template.dto';

const getTemplateDto = ({ name, type }): CreateTemplateDto => {
  const createTemplateDto: CreateTemplateDto = new CreateTemplateDto();
  createTemplateDto.name = name || 'Test Template';
  createTemplateDto.type = type;
  createTemplateDto.addedBy = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId();

  if (type === TemplateType.EMAIL) {
    createTemplateDto.subject = 'Test Subject';
    createTemplateDto.html = '<p>Test HTML</p>';
  } else {
    createTemplateDto.text = 'Test SMS';
  }

  return createTemplateDto;
};

describe('TemplatesService', () => {
  let service: TemplatesService;
  let templateModel: Model<Template>;

  beforeAll(async () => {});

  afterAll(async () => await closeInMongodConnection());

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [
        TestDbModule,
        MongooseModule.forFeature([
          { name: 'Template', schema: TemplateSchema },
        ]),
      ],
      providers: [TemplatesService, HelperService],
    }).compile();

    service = module.get<TemplatesService>(TemplatesService);
    templateModel = module.get<Model<Template>>    (getModelToken(Template.name));
  });

  afterEach(async () => {
    // Clear the templates collection after each test
    await templateModel.deleteMany({});
  });

  it('service should be defined', () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
  });

  describe('create', () => {
    it('should create a template', async () => {
      const createTemplateDto = getTemplateDto({
        name: null,
        type: TemplateType.EMAIL,
      });

      const result = await service.create(createTemplateDto);

      expect(result.name).toEqual(createTemplateDto.name);
      expect(result.type).toEqual(createTemplateDto.type);
      expect(result.subject).toEqual(createTemplateDto.subject);
      expect(result.html).toEqual(createTemplateDto.html);
    });
  });
});
```